# How can i dump the contents of a file that was opened with nano in a running process? (Linux)

Tags: linux, process, forensics, pid, hidden-file

I have run the command `ps -ef` and found the following :

```bash
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 12:30 ?        00:00:00 socat tcp-l:1024,reuseaddr,f
root           7       1  0 12:30 ?        00:00:00 socat EXEC:/usr/bin/nano /ho
testuser           10       7  0 12:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nano /home/testuser/testfile
root         141       1  0 13:44 ?        00:00:00 socat tcp-l:1024,reuseaddr,f
ctf          142     141  0 13:44 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash
ctf          148     142  0 13:49 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

So i want to view the contents of the testfile of which i dont have the full path nor can i find it (lets say its hidden and cant be found).

I went to `/proc/10/fd` and found the following :

```bash
total 0
dr-x------ 2 testuser testuser 0 Mar  3 12:33 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 testuser testuser 0 Mar  3 12:33 ..
lrwx------ 1 testuser testuser 64 Mar  3 12:33 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 testuser testuser 64 Mar  3 12:33 1 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 testuser testuser  64 Mar  3 12:33 2 -> 'pipe:[300396]'
lrwx------ 1 testuser testuser 64 Mar  3 12:33 3 -> 'socket:[300398]'
lrwx------ 1 testuser testuser 64 Mar  3 12:33 4 -> 'socket:[300399]'
```

I have read how to copy files that were deleted, but this file (the "testfile") is not deleted. Its just nowhere to be found.
My goal is to read this file based on the process that opened it with nano.

How could i go around that?

EDIT : the file was not previously saved and reopened. Imagine having opened a fresh file with nano, written something in it and the process still runs. The goal is to dump the contents that currently exist in there. I read that you could terminate nano and a .save file would be created, but i cant find such file. Maybe i doing something wrong.

Comment: Try command > filename   I use this and it works fine.

Comment: @John can you be more specific? What command are you refering to?

Comment: Any command  then pipe  >   to a file   .   Standard linux procedure   (May not work for an open Text Editor)  ..  So ave to a file first.

Answer (score 0):

Most text editors do not hold files open all the time; they read the entire thing into memory and close it. You can't get around that easily – you can dump the entire memory of a process (e.g. using `gcore` or inspecting it on the fly using gdb), but finding exactly where the loaded text buffer is will vary heavily from one editor to another. Often it won't be a single buffer, but a collection of individual lines that won't necessarily be in order.

(You could, for example, run `strings` against the generated core dump of the process; run it against another dump generated from a "fresh" 'nano' process; and use a tool to filter strings that are only in the first dump but not in both.)